# Passing argument to on click event of dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass arguments to onclick event of dynamically generated element. I have already seen the existing stackoveflow questions but it didn't answer my specific need.In this existing question , they are trying to access data using  $(this).text(); but I can't use this in my example.

[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

In below code snippet, I am trying to pass program and macroVal to onclick event but it doesn't work.

```
onClickTest = function(text, type) {
        if(text != ""){
        // The HTML that will be returned
        var program = this.buffer.program;
        var out = "<span class=\"";
        out += type + " consolas-text";
        if (type === "macro" && program) {
            var macroVal = text.substring(1, text.length-1);
            out += " macro1 program='" + program + "' macroVal='" + macroVal +  "'";
        }
        out += "\">";
        out += text;
        out += "</span>";
        console.log("out " + out);


        $("p").on("click" , "span.macro1" , function(e)
        {
            BqlUtil.myFunction(program, macroVal);
        });

    }else{
        var out = text;
    }
    return out;
```

};

console.log of out give me this

```
<span class="macro consolas-text macro1 program='test1' macroVal='test2'">{TEST}</span>
```

I have tried both this.program and program but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain values of `span` element attributes, since you include them in html:

```
$("p").on("click" , "span.macro" , function(e)
{
  BqlUtil.myFunction(this.getAttribute("program"), 
    this.getAttribute("macroVal"));
});
```

There are, however, several things wrong in your code.

- you specify `class` attribute twice in html assigned to `out`,
- single quotes you use are not correct (use `'`, not `’`),
- quotes of attribute values are messed up: consistently use either single or double quotes for attribute values

`var out = "<span class='";`

`...`

`out += "' class='macro' program='" + program + "' macroVal='" + macroVal + ;`

`...`

`out += "'>";`

- depending on how many times you plan to call `onClickTest`, you may end up with multiple `click` event handlers for `p span.macro`.

Comment: I have move the even handler code outside onClickTest. I realized later that if I put it inside the function , my function wasn't getting triggered at all and only onclickevent was getting triggered. can you give me a sample code snippet of how to pass argument ?

Comment: @user911 - Yes, I added it to my answer. You are producing incorrect html. Call `console.log(out);` before `return out;` and carefully inspect the result.

Comment: Your answer helped me fix my html quoting issues but I am still not able to pass the argument. I have upvoted your answer but still can't accept it. I have tried both this.program and program. It doesn't work. I have also updated my question to fix the quoting issue , please check.

Comment: @user911 where in my answer do you see the use of `this.program` or `program`? The console output, that you added to your question - is this what you expect? A single `class` attribute of `span` tag?

Comment: I am doing this inside my onclick function and this works .  $(this)[0].attributes.getNamedItem('program').nodeValue) . Your answer helped me to a lot of extent. If you can modify it and add this code snippet, I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @user911 there is no difference in the results of `$(this)[0].attributes.getNamedItem('program').nodeValue` and `this.getAttribute("program")`. I will not modify my answer to make code longer and more complicated.